# vitess installation failure at ./kvtctl.sh Remote error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing

Tags: kubernetes, installation, vitess

I am installing vitess in minikube. I am following the [instructions](https://vitess.io/getting-started/) for vitess installation in kubernetes, section: 6. Use vtctlclient to send commands to vtctld. I am getting the below error:

```
root@twinkle:~/go/src/vitess.io/vitess/examples/kubernetes# ./kvtctl.sh
Starting port forwarding to vtctld...
E1117 00:00:36.982524    4189 main.go:63] Remote error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
root@twinkle:~/go/src/vitess.io/vitess/examples/kubernetes#
```

I am stuck. Can anyone help here ?

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/vitessio/vitess/issues/1280) it's because `socat` is missing from the kubernetes Node; are you running CoreOS or Fedora Atomic on the Node?

Comment: I am running in ubuntu. socat is already installed.

Comment: Did you check if required number of pods are up and running, I suspect that the vtctld service is not up or taking time to come up and during that you hit this command.